# Storing a Tree (that won't be modified) for an iPhone app

Tags: iphone, tree, persistent-storage

I'm writing an iPhone app that will allow users to input a food and get the number of calories that food has. I want this app to autocomplete search queries, so that if someone types "oran" the option "orange" will pop up.  A tree seems to be the best data structure for implementing autocompletion.  Is there a way for me store a this tree so that my app doesn't have to rebuild it by reading an XML file every time it's run?

Answer (score 0):

Well no, you need to read in the tree on startup every time. You can use `NSCoding` to write the object tree to disk. But You will need to load any way.

Comment: He'll have to load at startup of course, but reading in XML can take a long time, especially on a large xml file. I would suspect that using NSCoding will result in faster startup times, but of course @Michael should test this as it would be case by case.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to avoid the disk access, the thing to do is to write code to print your tree out as an array in C syntax, e.g.

```
struct node {
    const char *name;
    struct node *left_child;
    struct node *right_child;
};

struct node tree[] = 
{
    { "parent", tree + 1, tree + 2 },
    { "left child", NULL, NULL},
    { "right child", NULL, tree + 3 },
    { "right grandchild", NULL, NULL },
};
```

and then put that into a .c file in your project. Then it will be loaded at program start when the executable is loaded into memory.

This technique, munging data into a header or c file and baking it into the executable, is pretty common on iOS for making initialization fast and easy.

Edit:
Also, properly speaking your use of a tree to hold individual characters of multiple different possible strings is known as a "trie."